# how to use External account inside charge method of laravel cashier

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using `laravel cashier` for an application where the user can subscribe in 3 ways

- Montly
- Yearly
- One time

I am using [create](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#creating-subscriptions) for `Monthly` and `Yearly` subscriptions and [charge](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#simple-charge) for one time.

The problem is I am not able to pass External Accounts details to the charge method(the amount should credit to this account from the user account) but for the `create` method it works perfectly.

For `create` I have used the below code, here the debited amount from the user will credit to the `$subscriptionOptions` account

```php
$subscription = $request->user()->newSubscription('default', 'price_premium')->withMetaData(['name' => $app->name])->create(null, [
    'email' => $request->user()->email,
    'name'  => $request->user()->name,
    ['metadata' => ['name' => $app->name]],
], $subscriptionOptions);
```

For `charge` I have used the below code, here the debited amount from the user will not credit to the `$subscriptionOptions` account

```php
$subscription = $request->user()->charge(200, $request->paymentMethodId, [
    'metadata' => [
        'app' => $app->name,
    ]
],$subscriptionOptions);
```

Can anyone help me out? Thank you.

Comment: External accounts(https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_accounts) are for paying money out. You can't charge them, that's not supported in Stripe. To emulate that kind of thing you would for example collect the same bank account details but create an ACH payment method fora Customer object instead (https://stripe.com/docs/ach)

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. What I want is when an amount is debited from the user's bank account, the debited amount should transfer to the `$subscriptionOptions` bank account. Currently, it is happing in the `create` method, I want to implement it to the `charge` method.